# Compile errors during translation compile

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate a theme using Poedit, every thing is alright except two strings which give me errors like this:

```
Error: 'msgstr' is not a valid PHP format string, unlike 'msgid'. Reason: The character that terminates the directive number 1 is not a valid conversation specifier.
```

The string itself is this:

```
% comments
```

Both errors are in strings having `% comment` (not sth like `% s`).
Now I have two problems:
1. How can I resolve these errors? Do I need to change theme code?
2. After getting these compile errors, I used .mo and .po files anyway but some phrases had been translated and some not! What is the reason to this?

EDIT: The PHP code translation associated to is:

```
comments_number( __('There are no comments so far', 'hbthemes'), __('There is <strong>1 comment</strong> so far', 'hbthemes'), __('There are <strong>% comments</strong> so far', 'hbthemes') );
```

Comment: Could you show the whole line of PHP code that is giving you the error?

Comment: Do you think I should change the PHP code?

Comment: What version of Poedit are you using?

Comment: @BenMiller 1.5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `POEdit` program. I used another app and it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` character is a special character in the gettext translation functions.  To escape the `%` character to use it in a string, change it to `%%`.

If you weren't using the `__()` translation functions, then a single `%` character would give you the number of comments. However, when you are using the translation functions, `%` is a special character with special meaning. If you want to actually include a `%` character in the string, you need to type it as `%%`. The `__()` function will send a single `%` on to the `comments_number` function, and you should get the number of comments in its place.

Your `comments_number` function should be:

```
comments_number( __('There are no comments so far', 'hbthemes'), __('There is <strong>1 comment</strong> so far', 'hbthemes'), __('There are <strong>%% comments</strong> so far', 'hbthemes') );
```

Comment: `%%` would show comments number? So what is the difference between single and double `%`?

Comment: @SAM I updated the answer with further explanation.

Comment: Changing `%` to `%%` made comment count double. It shows 2 comments 22 comments.